# Trivia API not returning proper JSON in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am using this API 
  https://market.mashape.com/pareshchouhan/trivia

for making widget in my site but when i am calling this API through CURL it is returning following error:

Any solution for that?

Here my code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pareshchouhan-trivia-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/getAllQuizQuestions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "MY_KEY",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  ));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

when i execute this PHP file, it is returning "Missing Mashape application key" in return data.

http://i.prntscr.com/5f98b1e8965f42eda29875543b052ec5.png

Comment: What you want to do??

Comment: I want all questions result in JSON format from that API but API returning something else as i have display in screenshot URL

Comment: Give your CURL portion of code.

Comment: We cannot see your screenshot!

Comment: @FrayneKonok Not working same error returning.

Comment: @deceze Please check this URL : http://i.prntscr.com/5f98b1e8965f42eda29875543b052ec5.png

Comment: We. Cannot. See. That. URL. It returns "Access denied".

Comment: @deceze, this is the screen shoot and for that he is asking.

Comment: @Frayne I don't think so. `prntscr.com` is returning an Access denied error, it's not a screenshot of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying you curl headers incorrectly. Look at the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option in the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php. Your code should look like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pareshchouhan-trivia-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/getAllQuizQuestions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-Mashape-Key: MY_KEY",
    "Accept: application/json"
));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: that is useful but  i am getting 504 gateway error that is that API problem.Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, your 504 error is now a timeout, from the APi docs I think you're missing the limit and page params, try adding them. If I've solved your original problem could you mark the answer as accepted.